# Can I use node http server in worker threads

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

**I know about cluster module, but question about worker_threads.**

Code example

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, threadId } = require('worker_threads')
const { createServer } = require('http')

if (isMainThread) {
  let w1 = new Worker(__filename)
  let w2 = new Worker(__filename)
} else {
  const server = createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end(`response from thread ${threadId}`)
  })
  server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`Thread ${threadId} is listening ${server.address().port}`)
  })
}
```

When I run this code on Windows, I get obvious error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
```

But it works without errors on WSL

```
$ node ./index.js
Thread 2 is listening 8080
Thread 1 is listening 8080
```

But in browser I always get response only from single worker, depends on order they started

Can I listen single http port in worker threads or not? If yes, how can I make load balancing on this port? Why nodejs allows to listen same port on WSL?

Comment: The workers would need to listen on different ports. It means that in your system you can only call `server.listen` with port 8080 once. For load balancing you gonna need to run reverse proxy like nginx in front of your app and configure it so it knowns what ports it should use for load balancing.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty obvious solution, but how can I listen same port on WSL? Is it specific behaviour on Ubuntu?

Comment: I tried your code on WSL2 and i get the same error I get in the windows. What version is your WSL? If v1 then that could be the reason. I know there were some strange things happening in v1, it could be one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot listen on the same port in worker threads. On Linux (Debian 10), your code fails with the expected error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080` as well. Expect it to fail in production environments.

The reason for this is that, even though Linux does support port sharing via SO_REUSEPORT, it's a fairly new feature and `libuv` does not implement the flag (not for `tcp`, at least). I have no idea why WSL is not producing an error for you, but as you can see, it does not do load balancing.

Here's how you can implement load balancing: use the `cluster` module instead, since that's what it is designed for. Or, listen on different ports and use a separate load balancer - though, if the processing is totally independent, you may be better off spawning separate, independent processes, instead of using the `worker_threads` module.